# Pencil Drawing in to Photoshop

Tags: path, drawing, photoshop

I have a simple drawing for a logo dine on a piece of paper using a pencil.  Pencil lines are very jagged and misshaped on certain places

I need to take this and digitize it so I can use it on all future graphics.  Turn it in to a simple transparent PNG or even actual line art if possible.

I scanned the original drawing.

I have Photoshop CS6 and was thinking about drawing paths.  However this seems to be very time consuming and not practical.

Is there a practical way to do this in Photoshop?

Are there apps that you can buy on Mac App store or somewhere else that would allow me to draw lines on top of the scanned image and will smoothen out the lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illustrator is the best tool for turning scanned drawings into digital art. It can turn each line into a vector that you can easily adjust.

If you want to draw new lines on top of your image, you can do this in Photoshop. Just add a new layer on top of the layer with the scanned image. You can also use Photoshop to smooth out your lines. But since your lines are misshaped, you're better off using Illustrator to reshape them.

Comment: How would you 'smooth out' lines in Photoshop?